# Python : datetime.strptime error when I used wx

Tags: python, wxpython, python-datetime

I found a curious bug.
When I used the library wx, my function strptime, which comes of datetime library, doesn't work.

Example :

```
from datetime import datetime
myDate2= datetime.strptime('Wed Feb 19 14:57:58 2020', '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
```

When I execute the previous code and wx.app() I have the following error:

```
myDate2= datetime.strptime('Wed Feb 19 14:57:58 2020', '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y') 
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-108-b41842200da1>", line 1, in <module>
myDate2= datetime.strptime('Wed Feb 19 14:57:58 2020', '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')

File "C:\Simu\WinPython_3741\python-3.7.4.amd64\Lib\_strptime.py", line 577, in _strptime_datetime
tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)

File "C:\Simu\WinPython_3741\python-3.7.4.amd64\Lib\_strptime.py", line 359, in _strptime
(data_string, format))

ValueError: time data 'Wed Feb 19 14:57:58 2020' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y'
```

What is the link between the datetime and wx ?
And how to fix this bug ?

Comment: can you please share the entire traceback

Comment: @Jeril Yes ! it's done

Answer (score 1):

Resolved !

This bug comes from localtime. I don't know why but when I execute wx.app(), my localtime change.

I discovered this thanks to the following command :

`from time import strftime,localtime
 print(strftime("%H:%M, %d %B %Y",localtime()))
 10:44, 20 février 2020`

To change the localtime, here is the code :

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')
```